# Spectral representation of complex non-negative definite function

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have a simple question about the notation used in the representation theorem of complex non-negative definite function in the book of Robert J Adler, *The geometry of random field*, P25.

Is $F$ just a measure in the standard Lebesgue integration theory, or the integration $A \mapsto \int_A dF(\lambda)$ is something more complicated (like Itô integration)?

[image: P25, The geometry of random field]